# Unable to install LetsEncrypt SSL on CentOS 7

Tags: ssl, centos, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am trying to install SSL Certificate to my website using Securing Apache with Let's Encrypt on CentOS 7.

My web server is (include version): Apache (cPanel)

My hosting provider, if applicable, is: GoDaddy

[followed this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7)  for that, STEP-1 and STEP-2 were successfull

with the understanding that no firewall has been setup in my VPS

```
    sudo yum install epel-release
    sudo yum install httpd mod_ssl python-certbot-apache
    sudo systemctl start httpd
    systemctl status httpd
    curl www.example.com ((Note: works))       
    sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

This last command generates an error, as follows:

```
sudo: certbot: command not found
```

I tried to install certbot by

```
sudo yum install certbot
```

and installed successfully

```
  Installed:
  certbot.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7

Dependency Installed:
  audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.8.1-3.el7_5.1         checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-6.el7                       libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-15.el7
  libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-11.el7             policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.5-22.el7           pyOpenSSL.x86_64 0:0.13.1-3.el7
  python-IPy.noarch 0:0.75-6.el7                     python-cffi.x86_64 0:1.6.0-5.el7                     python-enum34.noarch 0:1.0.4-1.el7
  python-idna.noarch 0:2.4-1.el7                     python-ndg_httpsclient.noarch 0:0.3.2-1.el7          python-ply.noarch 0:3.4-11.el7
  python-pycparser.noarch 0:2.14-1.el7               python-requests.noarch 0:2.6.0-1.el7_1               python-requests-toolbelt.noarch 0:0.8.0-1.el7
  python-six.noarch 0:1.9.0-2.el7                    python-urllib3.noarch 0:1.10.2-5.el7                 python-zope-component.noarch 1:4.1.0-3.el7
  python-zope-event.noarch 0:4.0.3-2.el7             python-zope-interface.x86_64 0:4.0.5-4.el7           python2-acme.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7
  python2-certbot.noarch 0:0.27.1-1.el7              python2-configargparse.noarch 0:0.11.0-1.el7         python2-cryptography.x86_64 0:1.7.2-2.el7
  python2-future.noarch 0:0.16.0-6.el7               python2-josepy.noarch 0:1.1.0-1.el7                  python2-mock.noarch 0:1.0.1-9.el7
  python2-parsedatetime.noarch 0:2.4-5.el7           python2-pyasn1.noarch 0:0.1.9-7.el7                  python2-pyrfc3339.noarch 0:1.0-2.el7
  python2-requests.noarch 0:2.6.0-0.el7              python2-six.noarch 0:1.9.0-0.el7                     pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.el7
  setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.8-2.el7

Complete!
```

I  again tried to request an SSL certificate for my domain.

```
   sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

this time it's  returning

```
   Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
   The requested apache plugin does not appear to be installed
```

/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

```
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,542:DEBUG:certbot.main:certbot version: 0.27.1
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,542:DEBUG:certbot.main:Arguments: ['--apache', '-d', 'example.com', '-d', 'www.example.com']
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,543:DEBUG:certbot.main:Discovered plugins: PluginsRegistry(PluginEntryPoint#manual,PluginEntryPoint#null,PluginEntryPoint#standalone,Plugi$
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,611:DEBUG:certbot.log:Root logging level set at 20
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,611:INFO:certbot.log:Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,613:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Requested authenticator apache and installer apache
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,613:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:No candidate plugin
    2018-11-02 08:15:55,614:DEBUG:certbot.plugins.selection:Selected authenticator None and installer None
```

**Note: I replaced example.com with my actual domain**

Any Help is highly Appreciated.Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the --standalone option (doesn't require any additional web server) but you have to shutdown any HTTP server using 443 port.

```
systemctl stop httpd 
/opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto --standalone -d mydomain.com
```

Make sure that your DNS record is pointing to the web server where you are running the certbot command.

It will save the certificate on /etc/letsencrypt/archive/mydomain.com/*.pem and update the symlink on /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/.

Now, update your Apache configs and restart it.

```
<VirtualHost>
    ...
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I recommend you to review your SSL and security settings to improve the apache configuration for your website.